# Call a Javascript function to update a filter in Nunjucks template?

Tags: javascript, templates, variables, nunjucks

Is it possible to call a js function and pass a variable into nunjucks template..?

```
         {{ filter }}
            {% set filterParam = orderBy() %}
            {{ filter }}
            {% for item in items | sort(true, true, filterParam) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const env = new nunjucks.Environment(/* ...loaders etc... */);
```

What do you mean by loaders?

Comment: [Loaders](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#loader)

Answer (score 0):

To use a function inside a template you should define it as global.

```
const nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
const env = new nunjucks.Environment(/* ...loaders etc... */); // or nunjucks.configure(...)
env.addGlobal('foo', () => 'OK');

const out = env.renderString(`{{ foo () }}`);
console.log(out);
```